# How can I change the background color of a button when clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

I researched a lot, and I found [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eYgdm/) looks like what I need, but, when I click the button, the *page* background is changing. I want the *button's* color to be changed when clicked, instead.

```css
div{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #5CB85C;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index:1;
}
label.btn {
    position: absolute;
    top:10px;
    left: 10px;
    z-index:2;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"]{
    display: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + div{
    background: #5BC0DE;
}
label + input[type="checkbox"]:checked{
    background: #000;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<label for="check" class="btn btn-default">Toggle background colour</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="check" />
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is fairly trivial. Simply move the "button" `label` element to *after* the checkbox so that you can select it with the `+` selector (this is called the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors); there is no previous sibling selector, unfortunately), and change the CSS to match. **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eYgdm/517/)**

```css
div{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #5CB85C;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index:1;
}
.btn {
    position: absolute;
    top:10px;
    left: 10px;
    z-index:2;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"]{
    display: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .btn {
    background: #5BC0DE;
}
/* label + input[type="checkbox"]:checked{
    background: #000;
} */ /* I've commented this last selector out as it is unused per Harry's point in the comments */
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="check" />
<label for="check" class="btn btn-default">Toggle background color</label>
<div></div>
```

Comment: I think you have probably missed to remove this selector - `label + input[type="checkbox"]:checked` :)

Comment: @Harry That was part of OP's code and is not interfering, so I did not remove it. I don't know what else is going on outside of the minimal example. :-)

Comment: Fair enough but I think (or assume) that OP tried to change label's color with that selector and it didn't work (for obvious reasons).

Answer (score 3):

To achieve what you want, in your css use `background-color` when the button is clicked.

":active" property is used for displaying clicked event style...

HTML:

```
<input type='button' class='btn' value='test'/>
```

CSS:

```
.btn {
    background-color:#00ff00;
}

.btn:active {
    background-color:#ff00ff;
}
```

[TEST](https://jsfiddle.net/5LopxnpL/)

Comment: This only changes the button color on hover; it doesn't toggle the background color on click.

Comment: That changes it to click, but it's only while clicking (the `:active` pseudo class). My interpretation (and the other answerer) is that OP wants it to toggle (and remain toggled) once clicked. After all, that seems to be the purpose of the checkbox hack used in the code above.

Comment: ok, I see. I was misled by "change color when clicked"... to me it sounded like only on active state.

Answer (score 2):

In css you can not go backward you should go forward like following. 
You need to put label after input box.

`+` is for the next sibling. There is no "previous sibling" selector.

```css
div{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #5CB85C;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index:1;
}
label.btn {
    position: absolute;
    top:10px;
    left: 10px;
    z-index:2;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"]{
    display: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label{
    background: #5BC0DE;
}
label + input[type="checkbox"]:checked{
    background: #000;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="check" />
<label for="check" class="btn btn-default">Toggle background colour</label>
<div></div>
```

Check [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eYgdm/518/)

Answer (score 2):

Try using css pseudo code:

```css
#check {
  display: none;
}
#check + label.btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 6px 8px;
  background: ghostwhite;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px;
}
#check:checked + label.btn {
  background: wheat;
}
#check + label.btn:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 2px;
}
#check + label.btn:active {
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px inset;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check" />
<label for="check" class="btn">Toggle background colour</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.nl [type=checkbox]:checked + span {
  background: #222222;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.nl label span {
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 9px;
  border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
  display: inline-block;
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
input[type="checkbox"], .checkbox-inline input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 4px \9;
  margin-left: -20px;
}
.nl label input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox nl">
            <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxx" name="rememberme" id="rememberme" value="1" checked="checkced"> Remember me<span></span></label>
   <input type="hidden" name="action" value="login">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + div{
    background: #5BC0DE;
}
```

to

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .btn {
    background: #5BC0DE;
}
```